# UnsupportedClassVersionError when opening custom controls in scene builder

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

My custom class:

```
public class IntegerField extends TextField {
    public IntegerField() {
        super();
        restrictToNumbersOnly();
    }

    public IntegerField(String text) {
        super(text);
        restrictToNumbersOnly();
    }
    public void restrictToNumbersOnly() {
         // Irrelevant
    }
}
```

I then try to add this custom class like this:

`<IntegerField fx:id="example" />`

IntelliJ's Scene Builder outputs this error:

`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: path/IntegerField has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0`

I've tried searching for this error but haven't found anything that explains why this shouldn't work. The examples I've found have indicated that it should be possible to just extend from the control class, and import it directly into the fxml file, and it does. It works perfectly when running the program, it's scene builder that is the issue.

I realize that this is a Java version issue, but the whole project is set to Java 9 (53) and I've experimented with changing the versions to no avail.

Comment: Does it help if you switch IDE to run under 1.9 JDK (see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879 )? Make sure to use the latest version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a fix for the in-built Scene Builder, but I have found a workaround on an external Scene Builder, using these steps:

- Install Gluon Scene Builder.
- Moving NumberField to it's own package.
- Making a custom fxml containing only a NumberField.
- Adding JavaFX Application to the package.
- Define the package as an artifact.
- Build artifact.
- Adding custom JAR in Gluon Scene Builder.

Answer (score 0):

You've compiled your class with Java 9's target level (thus generating a class version of 53), but you're trying to run it with Java 8.

Either run it with Java 9, or build it with a target language level of 8.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the project settings is set at Java 9, so I don't know where to start looking for this version mismatch.

Comment: @xZyph presumably in the same place you saw it's set to Java 9?

Comment: Oh yeah, I can probably set the project level to 8, but why doesn't it work at 9? Is my Scene Builder outdated, or do I have a separate setting for this?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your Scene Builder. The Java 8 binary you're using to execute it just can't read Java 9 bytecode.

Comment: Still got the error after downgrading project level to 8.

Comment: Did you rebuild? If you use a installed version of scenebuilder it should include a runtime. Using the latest version of scenebuilder should support java 9.

Comment: I am uncertain if I am changing the version correctly. I've tried going to Project Structure and changing the language level, something I realize might be something else. When doing this change I didn't rebuild, but was under the illusion that pressing apply would automatically do whatever required.

Other than that I only have the Java 9 SDK installed, so I struggle to see the logic anything being set to Java 8.

Comment: I am also using in-buildt Scene Builder in IntelliJ